# How to map a foreign key on an entity both as field and mapping in Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Background (short version): Symfony4 application in which I use a custom data layer over doctrine entity layer so the business logic layer is not dependent on the database schema. This is not changeable for the moment.

In some cases it's easier to use have the foreign key mapped as a field:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="article_id", type="string")
 */
protected $articleId;
```

but in other cases for the same entity I need the relation:

```
/**
 * @var Article
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Article")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $article;
```

to not have the same entity in 2 copies, I added the snippets above in one single class. If I hydrate the relation, everything works well ( $articleId is ignored ) but if only the $articleId is provided and $articles is null, doctrine will insert in DB null for the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution: I parse the class metadata, and if in `$class->associationMappings['joinColumnFieldNames']` exists fields that I also have as fields in the object, I remove the association mapping:

> doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php

```
private function doMerge($entity, array &$visited, $prevManagedCopy = null, array $assoc = [])
{
    $oid = spl_object_hash($entity);

    if (isset($visited[$oid])) {
        $managedCopy = $visited[$oid];

        if ($prevManagedCopy !== null) {
            $this->updateAssociationWithMergedEntity($entity, $assoc, $prevManagedCopy, $managedCopy);
        }

        return $managedCopy;
    }

    $class = $this->em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

    /* Code that I added */
    foreach ($class->associationMappings as $key => $mapping) {
        $joinColumns = $mapping['joinColumnFieldNames'] ?? [];

        if (array_intersect($joinColumns, $class->getColumnNames())) {
            unset($class->associationMappings[$key]);
            unset($class->reflFields[$key]);
        }
    }

    /* .... */

}
```

Is it ethically to do such thing?